# Downloading files from a S3 bucket to another server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a requirement that whenever files are placed in a S3 bucket, they need to be moved to an external VMC server. I have written a boto3 script that can download these files.

But how do I automate this process, so that whenever new files land on S3 bucket, script runs on external VMC server, and files are downloaded on it.

Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: You need to set up [s3 event notifications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/NotificationHowTo.html)

Comment: I thought of that too. But how a S3 event notification can be used to trigger a script present on a different server hosted outside AWS? Can you please elaborate on that.

Comment: Your script needs to be reachable *somehow*, e.g. listen on some ip / port that is reachable from S3, in that case you can trigger a lambda from the event notification which then calls that webhook.